# UIImagePicker opens Photos app in Landscape Mode always

Tags: ios, swift3, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller, landscape-portrait

UIImagePicker is always opening photos app in landscape mode while the controller is in portrait mode, and the device orientation is also portrait. Can anyone please help?

[image]

```
func actionSheet(_ actionSheet: UIActionSheet, didDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex: Int) {

    if buttonIndex == 1 {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {

            let controller = UIImagePickerController.init()
            controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
            controller.delegate = self
            controller.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

            })
        }
    }
    else if buttonIndex == 2 {

        let controller = UIImagePickerController.init()
        controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems no problem with this. I have made a sample code and it is working fine. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jw7krdlnpxxja1u/AADcv_-kpEGaFokjSbb7IHbRa?dl=0 . Is there anything else that is causing screen rotation?

Comment: I am doing exactly same as you have done in your Test orientation project, but strange thing is photos app is presenting in Landscape only.

Comment: Is there way you can share your code?

Comment: I have already shared the code above, where Imagepicker is being presented. 
Is there anything else you need to know?

Comment: Can you add this before presenting picker  controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext and let me know if that fixed issue.

Comment: Yup, added this line and this resolved my issue, thank you very much, You can add this in answer and i will accept this answer. You can up vote my question too. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157048/discussion-between-i-asifnoor-and-shuja-ud-din).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line before presenting viewcontroller. hope it will fix the issue

```
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```